# use inet_pton to store computed network address in ''struct in6_addr'' or "struct in6_addr.sin6_addr"

Tags: c, linux, tcp, ubuntu-10.04

Convert a text host address to a numeric address

```
int inet_pton( int af, const char * src, void * dst );
```

I have seen two different usages of this functions as follows:

Example 1:

http://man7.org/tlpi/code/online/book/sockets/i6d_ucase_cl.c.html

```
struct sockaddr_in6 svaddr;
...
inet_pton(AF_INET6, argv[1], &svaddr.sin6_addr)
```

Example 2:

http://www.qnx.com/developers/docs/6.4.1/neutrino/lib_ref/i/inet_pton.html

```
struct in6_addr in6addr;
...
inet_pton(AF_INET6, IN6ADDR, &in6addr))
```

Which one is correct? If all of them are correct, why each of them store the converted network address into totally different data structure?

Answer (score 1):

It's the same structure: `svaddr.sin6_addr` is of type `struct in6_addr`.

[`netinet/in.h`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/netinet_in.h.html)

> The  header shall define the sockaddr_in6 structure,
>   which shall include at least the following members:
>
> ```
> ...
> struct in6_addr  sin6_addr      IPv6 address.
> ```

As a mater of fact, anything that has enough size will do, as `inet_pton` is:

```
int inet_pton(int af, const char *restrict src, void *restrict dst);
                                                ^ anything
```